# Laravel subdomain named routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, subdomain

I have subdomain routes implemented like this:

```
Route::group(['domain' => iConfig::get('...')], function () {...}

Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}' . iConfig::get('...')], function () {...}
```

If I include two same resources file inside domain/subdomain like

```
Route::resource('test', 'SomeController');
```

I will have same named routes repeated two times. Will that cause an issue when calling a named route from the front-end part? Because if I want to fetch say `test.index`, will the app know based on current domain which index to fetch?

Comment: I'm working on the same problem too, did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Sorry, don't have access to the project anymore and I don't really remember what I did, it was a long time ago. Good luck and feel free to post your findings here

Answer (score 0):

Use prefix for names

```
Route::resource('product', 'ProductController', ['as' => 'admin']);
```

this will generate name routes like **admin.product.store**.

then u can use

```
route('admin.product.store')
```

for the admin subdomain